# Access denied while redirecting output from plink to local file

Tags: batch-file, plink

I am trying to redirect my `plink` command file output (That executes a script on UNIX server) to another file. But I am getting  **Access Denied** issue while redirecting output.

Batch file:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\PuTTY" 

plink -t w44gq8asd@USA7061UX02.wv.abcd.net -pw T@12Ts "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin /opt/siebel/w44gq8asd/a.sh" > output.txt

cmd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your working directory is in `Program Files`, where you do not have a write permissions, so it's only natural, that you are getting "Access denied".

You have to write the output file to a different folder:

```
plink ... > C:\path\where\you\can\write\to\output.txt
```

---

If you wanted to write to the path, where your batch file is, what about not changing the working directory in the first place:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink" ... > output.txt
```

(and remove the `cd` command)

Comment: To write to the location where the batch file is use `... > "%~dp0output.txt"`, because `> output.txt` points to the current working directory, which is not necessarily the same...